# How to find the greatest value combination of matched items in a paired list?

Tags: python

The goal is to create a python function that will take two input variables (**recipes**, a list of dictionaries and **ingredients_collected**, a list of ingredient pairs) and attempt to return the greatest **value** (based on completed recipes as defined below) of combinations. It will need to compare a list of "pairs" such as "carb, pasta" against a requirement called ingredients_needed structured as a comma-separated list of required ingredients, such as "pasta" **or** "carb". The rules are that an ingredient pair **can only be used once when iterating through combinations.**

The following variables are:

```
recipes = [
{'player_name': 'Kei', 'recipe_name': 'Sushi (Fish)', 'ingredients_needed': 'rice, fish', 'item_value': 2,
 'bonus_ingredient': '', 'bonus_value': ''},
{'player_name': 'Kei', 'recipe_name': 'Sushi (Veggie)', 'ingredients_needed': 'rice, veggie', 'item_value': 2,
 'bonus_ingredient': '', 'bonus_value': ''},
{'player_name': 'Kei', 'recipe_name': 'Tempura (Veggie)', 'ingredients_needed': 'veggie', 'item_value': 2,
 'bonus_ingredient': 'sauce', 'bonus_value': '1'},
{'player_name': 'Kei', 'recipe_name': 'Tempura (Fish)', 'ingredients_needed': 'fish', 'item_value': 2,
 'bonus_ingredient': 'sauce', 'bonus_value': '1'},
{'player_name': 'Kei', 'recipe_name': 'Yakitori (Protein)', 'ingredients_needed': 'protein', 'item_value': 3,
 'bonus_ingredient': 'sauce', 'bonus_value': '1'},
{'player_name': 'Kei', 'recipe_name': 'Yakitori (Sub)', 'ingredients_needed': 'sub', 'item_value': 3,
 'bonus_ingredient': 'sauce', 'bonus_value': '1'},
{'player_name': 'Kei', 'recipe_name': 'Ramen (Protein)', 'ingredients_needed': 'pasta, veggie, protein',
 'item_value': 4, 'bonus_ingredient': '', 'bonus_value': ''},
{'player_name': 'Kei', 'recipe_name': 'Ramen (Sub)', 'ingredients_needed': 'pasta, veggie, sub',
 'item_value': 4, 'bonus_ingredient': '', 'bonus_value': ''}
    ]
```

and

```
ingredients_collected = ['veggie, carrot', 'veggie, carrot', 'sub, seitan']
```

The 'ingredients_needed' is a list of ingredients that are required to match that recipe. The "ingredients_collected" is a list of ingredient pairs. Each pair represents one ingredient. The pairs are separated by a comma. If **either of the items** in the pair match the "ingredients_needed" it counts as a match. When all of the "ingredients_needed" are matched in a recipe the "**item_value**" is awarded. An ingredient pair can only be used once in a match, for example if 'veggie, cabbage' is used to match the 'cabbage' then it cannot be used again.

The function should accept the input of "recipes" and "ingredients_collected". This function will need to return the highest scoring item_value combinations of recipes by iterating through all possible combinations of matches and returns two variables: the highest scoring total item_values of matched recipes and the number of matched recipes. Here are the vital rules of the function:

- Ingredients_collected are ingredient-pairs that represent one individual ingredient
- A match is valid if either item in the ingredient-pair matches to an item in "ingredients_needed", and a complete match is valid when **all of "ingredients_needed"** have been matched for a recipe.
- We must also check if "ingredients_collected" matches the "**bonus_ingredient**" and add the "**bonus_value**" to the item_value. A bonus_ingredient is only valid if the recipe is a complete match.

*The expected return value from the function should be (7, 3) for the 'veggie, carrot' matching twice to 'Tempura (Veggie)' (item_value = 2) and once to the 'Yakitori (Sub)' (item_value = 3) which results in  2+2+3=7, for 3 matches/recipes.*

This is as far as I could get before hitting a mental wall with the function:

```
def calculate_max_recipe_value(recipes: List[dict], ingredients_collected: List[str]) -> Tuple[int, int, list, list]:
    used_ingredients = []
    final_recipes = []
    max_value = 0
    max_recipes = 0

    for recipe in recipes:
        ingredients_needed = recipe['ingredients_needed'].split(', ')
        bonus_ingredient = recipe['bonus_ingredient']
        bonus_value = int(recipe['bonus_value']) if recipe['bonus_value'] else 0
        item_value = int(recipe['item_value'])

        for ingredient_pair in ingredients_collected:
            ingredient1, ingredient2 = ingredient_pair.split(', ')
            if ingredient1 in ingredients_needed and ingredient1 not in used_ingredients:
                used_ingredients.append(ingredient1)
                final_recipes.append(recipe['recipe_name'])
                item_value += bonus_value if ingredient1 == bonus_ingredient else 0
                break
            elif ingredient2 in ingredients_needed and ingredient2 not in used_ingredients:
                used_ingredients.append(ingredient2)
                final_recipes.append(recipe['recipe_name'])
                item_value += bonus_value if ingredient2 == bonus_ingredient else 0
                break

        if len(used_ingredients) == len(ingredients_needed):
            max_value += item_value
            max_recipes += 1
            used_ingredients = []
            final_recipes = []

    return max_value, max_recipes, used_ingredients, final_recipes
```

This function is returning `(5, 2, ['veggie', 'sub'], ['Ramen (Protein)', 'Ramen (Sub)'])` instead of the expected `(7, 3, ['veggie', 'veggie','sub'], ['Tempura (Veggie)', 'Tempura (Veggie)', 'Yakitori (Sub)'])` I am struggling to implement a mechanism for finding the greatest matching combination under these rules as the `len(used_ingredients) == len(ingredients_needed):` is not iterating to the actual highest scoring combination. I may be overthinking the solution here -- a tip in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the problem down into simpler steps. Don't try to do everything all at once. Think about what data-structures will help you achieve your goal, and also about how adapting the input arguments to different representations can help you. I hope this illustrates to you a clean way to tackle these problems by first breaking them down.

---

To start things off, I would make a class to represent the recipes. This will avoid a lot of troublesome lookups. I would also convert the `ingredients_needed` to a list of sets. This will help with overlap detection, and gets the string splitting out of the way at the start.

```
class Recipe:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.player_name = args['player_name']
        self.recipe_name = args['recipe_name']
        self.ingredients_needed = set(args['ingredients_needed'].split(", "))
        self.item_value = int(args['item_value'] or 0)
        self.bonus_ingredient = args['bonus_ingredient']
        self.bonus_value = int(args['bonus_value'] or 0)

recipe_data = [Recipe(args) for args in recipes]
ingredients_data = [
    set(ingredients.split(", "))
    for ingredients in ingredients_collected
]
```

Now that we have the data in a nice format, we can define a method which takes one recipe and one set of ingredients to compute a single score. Because we're using sets for the data, we can take advantage of the overloaded set union and subtraction logic! We can denote no match at all with a negative value. From your description this is what I came up with:

```
def determine_score(recipe, ingredients):
    # Filter out cases without any matches
    if len(recipe.ingredients_needed & ingredients) == 0:
        return -1

    score = 0

    # There is complete overlap of the ingredients required
    if len(recipe.ingredients_needed - ingredients) == 0:
        score += recipe.item_value

    # The bonus ingredient is in the ingredients
    if recipe.bonus_ingredient in ingredients:
        score += recipe.bonus_value

    return score
```

Notice here how because we used a class, we can take advantage of attributes on the class without dict style lookups.

To find the best recipe for an ingredient list, we can compare the list to each recipe. We can then pipe that into `max`.

```
def max_score(recipe_data, ingredients):
    scores = {
        recipe.recipe_name: determine_score(recipe, ingredients)
        for recipe in recipe_data
    }
    max_score_name = max(scores, key=scores.get)
    return max_score_name, scores[max_score_name]
```

Now we just need to tally up the total score and the total amount of recipes.

```
def find_total_score(recipe_data, ingredients_data):
    total_score = 0
    total_recipes = 0

    for ingredients in ingredients_data:
        recipe_name, recipe_value = max_score(recipe_data, ingredients)
        if recipe_value >= 0:
            print(f"Making {recipe_name} with {ingredients} for a score of {recipe_value}")
            total_score += recipe_value
            total_recipes += 1
        else:
            print(f"Found no recipe for {ingredients}")
    return total_score, total_recipes
```

To wrap it up:

```
def calculate_max_recipe_value(recipes, ingredients_collected):
    recipe_data = [Recipe(args) for args in recipes]
    ingredients_data = [
        set(ingredients.split(", "))
        for ingredients in ingredients_collected
    ]
    return find_total_score(recipe_data, ingredients_data)
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> calculate_max_recipe_value(recipes, ingredients_collected)
Making 'Tempura (Veggie)' with {'veggie', 'carrot'} for a score of 2
Making 'Tempura (Veggie)' with {'veggie', 'carrot'} for a score of 2
Making 'Yakitori (Sub)' with {'sub', 'seitan'} for a score of 3
(7, 3)
```